# Get ajax request result as input for second ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a bit stuck with the below issue, my code is similar to this:

```
function (){
  var myVar = myFirstAjaxFunction()
  $.ajax({
    url: myUrl + myVar
    ....
  })
}
```

My first ajax function is returning a string that I would like to use in the end of my function, but I do not know how to wait for the first function to be done.

I hope this is clear, thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
        var a = data;
        $.ajax({
            data: 'data=' + a,
            success: function (data2) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Or you pass callback :

```
function myFirstAjaxFunction (callback){

$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
     callback(data);
   }
});

}
```

and usage :

```
myFirstAjaxFunction(function(data){
//call 2nd ajax
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post(url1,{ params:myVar}, function(result) {
    $.post(url2,{params:result}, function(final_result) {
       //use final_result here... :)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take help of callback function, please look at the below code. will help you.

```
function myFirstAjaxFunction(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: "demo_test.txt",
        success: function(result){
         return callback('your-string');
        }
    });
}

function (){
  myFirstAjaxFunction(function(myVar){
  $.ajax({
    url: myUrl + myVar
    ....
  })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await):

```
async function (){
  var myVar = await $.ajax({
    url: firstAjaxCallUrl
    ....
  })
  $.ajax({
    url: myUrl + myVar
    ....
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the promise from the ajax call. Example snippet for your reference

```
function (){
   myFirstAjaxFunction()
}

function myFirstAjaxFunction() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    success: function(response) {
      //response of the first api call
      secondApiCall(responseoffirst);
    }
  });
}

function secondApiCall(value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```